# Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, mapping, automapper

I am using Automapper with NPoco in my Web Api project.
Here is my Dto's and models:

```
[TableName("Component")]
    public class ComponentDto
    {
        [Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string BotanicalName { get; set; }
    }

[TableName("FormulaComponent")]
    public class FormulaComponentDto
    {
        [Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Reference(ReferenceType.Foreign, ColumnName = "ComponentId", ReferenceMemberName = "Id")]
        public ComponentDto Component { get; set; }

    }

public class Component
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string BotanicalName { get; set; }
}

public class FormulaComponent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Component Component { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to map one model to another using Automapper. Here is my automapper profile:

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            //From Model to Dto
            Mapper.CreateMap<FormulaComponent, FormulaComponentDto>().ReverseMap();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ComponentDto, Component>().ReverseMap();
        }
    }
```

But when I'm trying, I have an exeption: "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping" :

```
public IEnumerable<FormulaComponent> GetAll()
        {
            var formulaComponents = _repository.Get().Include(x => x.Component).ToList();
            return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<FormulaComponentDto>, IEnumerable<FormulaComponent>>(formulaComponents);
        }
```

UPD: 
automapper initialized into LightInject:

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public static void InitLightInject(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var container = new ServiceContainer();

            Mapper.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfile>();
            container.Register<IMappingEngine>(c => Mapper.Engine);
         }
     }
```

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: Please add code where the profile gets registered (Mapper initialization)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. 
In my `FormulaComponent` class it was incorrect namespase for `Component` class:
 `System.ComponentModel` instead of `Domain.Components`